# How add jQuery to SoloLearn Playground section?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a JavaScript editor in www.sololearn.com/Codes/
when I put $ sign for a jQuery it says that $ is undefined.

How can I add a jQuery to my code so it will work but keep the code separated like in the editor: one slot for HTML, another slot for CSS, another for JavaScript.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <Title>Sum To Coins - Dynamic Programming</Title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainScreen">
        <p id="instructions">Insert a sum to turn it into coins</p>  

        <button class='Button' id="btn1">Button</button>
        <button class='Button' id="btn2">Button</button>
        <button class='Button' id="btn3">Button</button>
        <br>

        <p id="resultField">The coins are: </p>

        <p id="matrixField"> </p>


    </div>

    <div id="pickCoinsScreen">
        <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
.Button:active, .active {
    background-color:red;
    color: white;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.Button').click(function(
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your Javascript code has few errors so i have solved that and also implemented some best practices of using **jQuery's "DOMReady" function**.

```
$(function(){
   $('.Button').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

within the `<head>` tag I have inserted the link to google hosted library of `jQuery`. Now your `<head>` element contains this code.

```
<head>
    <Title>Sum To Coins - Dynamic Programming</Title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

**Side note:** I have removed `e.preventdefault()` because it's not necessary in this case.

I have tested it on solo-learn, it seems its working.